# Mocha Unit Testing Mongoose Models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm struggling to figure out the correct (i.e. not a hack) way to write these unit tests for my NodeJS app.

In server.js, I connect mongoose to the DB running on localhost:27017.  When I run my mocha tests, I would like to connect to a *different* mongoDB instance running on localhost:37017, so that I am not running my tests against a live database.  When I require mongoose in test.js and try to connect, mongoose throws an error, saying "Trying to open unclosed connection."

I have tried closing the current connection in test.js, however it doesn't work for some reason.

My question is: What is the proper way to connect to a test DB in one file, but continue letting server.js connect to the live DB?

My code is below:

```
// test.js
var app = require('../lib/server') // This connects mongoose to a database
var assert = require('assert');
var httpstatus = require('http-status');
var superagent = require('superagent');

// Connect to mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:37017/testDB'); // THIS THROWS ERROR because server.js is connecting to localhost:27017/liveDB

// Models we will be testing
var thing = require('../models/thing.js');

describe('Thing', function() {

    before(function() {
        // Clear the database here
    }

    beforeEach(function() {
        // Insert, modify, set up records here
    }

    it('saves the thing to the database', function() {
        // Save and query a thing here (to the test DB)
    });
});
```

Comment: Generally, these things are configured outside your app, so you would use a different configuration during testing. But as a quick hack (sorry...), you could try and see if `mongoose.disconnect()` before calling `.connect()` in your test file works.

Comment: Even with `mongoose.disconnect()` before I connect to the DB, it still throws a "trying to open unclosed connection" error.

Could you embellish on how to set up a configuration file like you mentioned?  I'm a very new (less than 2 weeks) node developer

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (although it's a hack):

```
// Connect to mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
before(function(done) {
  mongoose.disconnect(function() {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:37017/testDB');
    done();
  });
});

// Models we will be testing (see text)
var thing = require('../models/thing.js');

...

describe(...)
```

It might be necessary to load your model inside the `disconnect` handler as well, as it may "attach" to the original connection otherwise.

Again, this is still quite a hack, and I would suggest moving the configuration of your database to an external configuration file of some sorts, or use an environment variable, which could be relatively easy to implement:

```
// server.js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/prodDB')

// test.js
process.env.MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:37017/testDB'
var app = require('../lib/server');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i env-cmd --save   // install this package
```

create config directory in the root of the project and create dev.env and test.env files in the config folder.

in test.env file, configure your test environment like this:

```
PORT=4000

MONGODB_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbTestName
```

then in the package.json, load the settings of test.env into the test environment.

```
"test": "env-cmd  -f ./config/test.env jest --watchAll --runInBand"
```

here we required the module and then loaded the test.env settings here.

env-cmd package will add all the settings from the .env files into process.env object depending on your environment. when you run  `run npm test`, your app will use the settings inside the test.env.

so in your application this is how you should use the MONGODB_URL to connect mongoose.

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to mongodb");
  });
```

you will use settings inside the dev.env for your dev environment. Now you need to tweak the dev script inside the package.json

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env node src/index.js",
```

now when you run

```
npm run dev
```

your app load the settings from the dev.env